# Query some properties on relation with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, viewmodel

I have a mapped model with Nhibernate like this:

```
public class A
{
   public virtual long Id { get; set; }
   public virtual long Number { get; set; }

   /* and other 20 properties... */
}


public class B
{
   public virtual long Id { get; set; } 
   public virtual A ItemA { get; set; }
   public virtual string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to create a query (queryover, linq, hql etc... anyway) to get a `List<B>` and fill ItemA property with just Id and Number properties because I need only this properties (I have lots of properties in A class and I will not use it on my results). Is there any way to do this or should I create a `ViewModel`? If I need to create a `ViewModel`, how can I do this with `QueryOver`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to create a view model, like following:

```
public class BViewModel
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; } 
    public virtual AViewModel ItemA { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class AViewModel
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual long Number { get; set; }
}
```

Now you oculd query it with linq like this:

```
var listOfB = session.Query<B>()
    .Select(b => new BViewModel
        {
            Id = b.Id,
            Name = b.Name,
            Date = b.Date,
            ItemA = new AViewModel 
                {
                    Id = b.ItemA.Id,
                    Number = b.ItemA.Number,
                },
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi friend. It will return `List<B>` or `List<BViewModel>` ? The BViewModel and AViewModel is just to help to construct the query?

Comment: It will return `List<BViewModel>`. Also you could try to replace calling `BViewModel` and `AViewModel` constructors with `B` and `A`. So  it will return `List<B>`.

Comment: Thank you man, I'll try it later and I'll back to check your awser. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

using `QueryOver`, you can use `JoinAlias` to join A with B, and `SelectList` to retrieve only the properties that you want.
Then use `TransformUsing` to transform the result into whatever format you want.
Something along the lines of:

```
A aTemplate = null;
s.QueryOver<B>().
  .JoinAlias(() => aTemplate)
  .Where (/*whatever conditions*/)
  .SelectList(list => list
      .Select(() => aTemplate.Id)
      .Select(() => aTemplate.Number)
  .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBeanTransformer)
  .List<A/*or some DTO*/>();
```

Comment: Hi @sJhonny thank you for the awser. This query will give me a List<B> with all properties of B and Id and Number of A filled? Thank you

Comment: depends on what you define in your `SelectList`. As I've defined it, it would retrieve only `A`s. check out this explanation on QueryOver for more details: http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx

Comment: I noticed a downvote on my answer- i'd appreciate an explanation as to where I was wrong. thanks.